# Edit a question to remove incorrect assertion that your answer is incorrect

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027165/cumulative-sum-of-30-rows-slow-code-need-improvement/) with some example code and a clear caveat (in a fairly quick update to the answer) that it would not work perfectly as is b/c of minor implementation details. I noted what part was not implemented and where the asker should look to find documentation for implementing it.

The asker came back sometime later and updated the question to paste in my code (as is) and its output at the top of the question, with the words, "This doesn't work." I didn't see it and didn't respond, so they posted another update with my code, now slightly modified, and the output, saying "this still doesn't work." I commented and pointed out the line where I had said that it wouldn't work as is and what to do to get it working. Turned out that the user had managed to get it to work while I was gone. They accepted my answer, but the two big updates at the top of the post, almost as long as the (quite long) question, saying "this code doesn't work", remained. You now have to scroll down more than a full screen just to see where the question starts, and the mistaken impression is given that the code in the accepted answer doesn't answer the question.

I tried to edit the question by removing the now-outdated updates, but my edit was rejected by a few people  with the reason of "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner." I understand that this is a drastic change, but all I did was revert to the original question, which is what the asker really wanted answered - the content I deleted was a result of their not seeing/noticing my caveat.

I know that I am biased, since I of course don't want a question which twice says that my answer is wrong, but I do think that leaving in the updates will be misleading to future readers. The question is not an uncommon one, and I think it might be helpful to many people in the future. Was it wrong to remove the updates? Or is it fine, but I have a conflict of interest and shouldn't be the one to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes reviewers don't spend much time reviewing or don't read the post carefully. Did you explain your intent in the edit coments? Sometimes that helps, though not always. In any case, I'm sure someone will fix it now that you've pointed it out.

Update - I rolled back the two edits that incorporated your code.

Comment: I did explain my intent, but maybe not enough. Thanks.

Comment: Some reviewers just aren't very careful, and it only takes 3 to reject an edit. Bad luck. It won't have any lingering ill effects, so don't concern yourself too much.

Comment: @bsg In the review queue, reviewers see the post in isolation, with the differences highlighted. Unless they really study the context and history, it might look like removing a chunk of code is a bad edit. I had a similar case very recently, and rolled back the edit (fortunately I don't need reviews anymore). Not only did it create a disconnect between question and answer, it actually could have looked like I plagiarized the code from the question for my answer, while it was in fact copied from the answer into the question.